# How to retrieve xml elements in android using DOM

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have created an xml file and stored in my sdcard.I am using DOM parser to retrieve it.My xml file is like.I have used a simple xml file for demo.It is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <staff>
        <word>1</word>
        <meaning>one</meaning>

    </staff>
    <staff>
        <word>2</word>
        <meaning>two</meaning>

    </staff>
</root>
```

In my activity i have an autocompletetextview.In it when i enter 1 which is given in word it should show the value "one" which is given in its meaning.Is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: See [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Comment: It would be wiser to use SAX parser or XmlPullParser, since you don't modify this xml file as far as I understand. These solutions are more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get node list by using `getElementsByTagName("staff")`

get child nodes `getChildNodes()`

Now get nodename `getNodeName()` and node value `getNodeValue()`

See this below code:

```
 Element root=doc.getDocumentElement();    
                 NodeList nodeList=root.getElementsByTagName("staff");
                 for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++)
                 {
                     Node statenode=nodeList.item(i);  

                     NodeList idList= statenode.getChildNodes();
                    for(int j=0;j<idList.getLength();j++)
                    {
                      Node property = idList.item(j);
                  String name = property.getNodeName();


                  if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("word"))
                  {
                     //Read your values here

                      Log.e("",property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

                   }
                  if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("meaning"))
                  {
                      //Read your values here
                      Log.e("",property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

                   }
                    }

                   }
```